# Getting PostgreSQL running on OSX 10.8.2 (conflict with OS X version of PostgreSQL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PostgreSQL Permission denied Error on Unix domain socket “/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432” - Lion Server 10.7.3 or Lion Server 10.7.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377416/postgresql-permission-denied-error-on-unix-domain-socket-var-pgsql-socket-s-p)

I'm trying to teach myself Rails and would like to be able to deploy to Heroku.  Heroku wants me to use PostgreSQL so I tried to install it using homebrew.

Now when I try and interact with the database it tells me:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
      Is the server running locally and accepting
      connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

That led me to this [question/answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21587/postgresql-is-running-locally-but-i-cannot-connect-why).  I tried to follow wolftron's solution, but when I get to the final step:

> then use the pg_ctl binary in /usr/local/bin to start the right postgres server successfully (which is where $PATH comes in – make sure which pg_ctl resolves to /usr/local/bin/pg_ctl, or just always call it explicitly).

I run into another fun issue:

```
localhost: which pg_ctl
pg_ctl not found
```

So now I try and track down pg_ctl:

```
sudo find / -name pg_ctl
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
/usr/local/bin/archive/pg_ctl
```

So pg_ctl is in /usr/local/bin/archive/?  Why is it there?  Did I botch the homebrew install?  At this point I started to try and think about how to move it to /usr/local/bin, but its starting to feel like I'm going down a rabbit hole.

Any ideas how to fix this?  I am close to just wiping OSX and doing a fresh install, but I'm afraid I'll just get the same issues again...

Comment: This has been asked soo many times. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114411/postgresql-socket-error-when-running-djangos-syncdb-mac-os-10-7-5 and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133870/postgresql-socket-error-on-osx-10-7-3-when-running-djangos-syncdb and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443738/postqresql-in-rails-how-do-i-make-the-server-run-locally-and-accept-connections

Comment: In fairness, it's been asked too many times because Apple's decision to place a preinstalled PostgreSQL on the default PATH is a nightmare for users.

Comment: I've tried the stuff in those links and always seem to get another error. I'm afraid now I've screwed the install up so bad that there is no turning back - I think I may just go back to mysql until I can find some time for a full system wipe.  Getting this set up is ridiculously complex.

Comment: @Demosophy Your best option on Mac OS X is to use TCP/IP by specifying `-h localhost` in `psql`, and specifying a hostname in your ruby database configuration.

Comment: @Demosophy  I feel your pain.  Three points: 1) you *can* have one database in development and another in production (although wouldn't recommend SQLLite in dev, and this is probably a short-term workaround), 2) you can just use the Apple-installed PostgreSQL, and 3) if you want to install via homebrew (or reinstall) I do recommend getting back to a known state (which homebrew makes easy -- just delete /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql); then follow the instructions on the posts above.  It's worth it.

Comment: @tharrison, Craig Ringer- thanks both.  I will give this approach a try and see if I can make it work.